# Laravel 4.1 - display time format from mysql column TIME

Tags: mysql, time, laravel-4

I have a column in mysql database named **time_start** which type is **TIME**.
I am trying to format the displayed time in my view from **H:i:s** to simple **H:i**, so instead of **20:00:00** i will get **20:00**.
Firstly i thought i can use **format()** method, but it's supposed to be used with timestamps, so of course i get error **Call to a member function format() on a non-object**.
I'm sure it's a simple question, but i can't solve this.

**-EDIT-**
Forgt to mention. I am working with a many to many relationship and i'm calling my data like:

```
$schedule->time_start
```

Here i would like to show the time in **H:i** format, not **H:i:s**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried an accessor method? I.e. in the `Schedule` model,

```
/**
 * Return a truncated version of the timestamp.
 * @param $value     original value of attribute
 * @return string truncated value
 */
public function getTimeStartAttribute($value)
{
    // Input is HH:MM:SS
    return substr($value, 0, 5);
    // Output is HH:MM
}
```

Then `$schedule->time_start` ought to return the time in HH:MM format.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what i wanted :) I totaly forgot to insert **$value** into brackets! Seriously, i need to start sleeping more than 5 hours a day ;) Thank you very much Iserni.